# Cachegrind: Why so many cache misses?

Tags: c++, performance, profiling, cpu-cache, cachegrind

I'm currently learning about various profiling and performance utilities under Linux, notably valgrind/cachegrind.

I have following toy program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int
main() {
    const unsigned int COUNT = 1000000;

    std::vector<double> v;

    for(int i=0;i<COUNT;i++) {
        v.push_back(i);
    }

    double counter = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<COUNT;i+=8) {
        counter += v[i+0];
        counter += v[i+1];
        counter += v[i+2];
        counter += v[i+3];
        counter += v[i+4];
        counter += v[i+5];
        counter += v[i+6];
        counter += v[i+7];
    }

    std::cout << counter << std::endl;
}
```

Compiling this program with `g++ -O2 -g main.cpp` and running `valgrind --tool=cachegrind ./a.out`, then `cg_annotate cachegrind.out.31694 --auto=yes` produces following result:

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Auto-annotated source: /home/andrej/Data/projects/pokusy/dod.cpp
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Ir I1mr ILmr        Dr    D1mr    DLmr        Dw D1mw DLmw 

        .    .    .         .       .       .         .    .    .  #include <iostream>
        .    .    .         .       .       .         .    .    .  #include <vector>
        .    .    .         .       .       .         .    .    .  
        .    .    .         .       .       .         .    .    .  int
        7    1    1         1       0       0         4    0    0  main() {
        .    .    .         .       .       .         .    .    .      const unsigned int COUNT = 1000000;
        .    .    .         .       .       .         .    .    .  
        .    .    .         .       .       .         .    .    .      std::vector<double> v;
        .    .    .         .       .       .         .    .    .  
5,000,000    0    0 1,999,999       0       0         0    0    0      for(int i=0;i<COUNT;i++) {
3,000,000    0    0         0       0       0 1,000,000    0    0          v.push_back(i);
        .    .    .         .       .       .         .    .    .      }
        .    .    .         .       .       .         .    .    .  
        3    0    0         0       0       0         0    0    0      double counter = 0;
  250,000    0    0         0       0       0         0    0    0      for(int i=0;i<COUNT;i+=8) {
  250,000    0    0   125,000       1       1         0    0    0          counter += v[i+0];
  125,000    0    0   125,000       0       0         0    0    0          counter += v[i+1];
  125,000    1    1   125,000       0       0         0    0    0          counter += v[i+2];
  125,000    0    0   125,000       0       0         0    0    0          counter += v[i+3];
  125,000    0    0   125,000       0       0         0    0    0          counter += v[i+4];
  125,000    0    0   125,000       0       0         0    0    0          counter += v[i+5];
  125,000    0    0   125,000 125,000 125,000         0    0    0          counter += v[i+6];
  125,000    0    0   125,000       0       0         0    0    0          counter += v[i+7];
        .    .    .         .       .       .         .    .    .      }
        .    .    .         .       .       .         .    .    .  
        .    .    .         .       .       .         .    .    .      std::cout << counter << std::endl;
       11    0    0         6       1       1         0    0    0  }
```

What I'm worried about is this line:

```
125,000    0    0   125,000 125,000 125,000         0    0    0          counter += v[i+6];
```

**Why this line has so many cache-misses?** The data are in contiguous memory, each iteration I'm reading 64-bytes of data (assuming the cache line is 64 bytes long).

I'm running this program on Ubuntu Linux 18.04.1, kernel 4.19, g++ 7.3.0.
Computer is AMD 2400G.

Comment: What is column legend? What is `D1mr`?

Comment: @VTT From the http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html : `I cache reads (Ir, which equals the number of instructions executed), I1 cache read misses (I1mr) and LL cache instruction read misses (ILmr).

D cache reads (Dr, which equals the number of memory reads), D1 cache read misses (D1mr), and LL cache data read misses (DLmr).

D cache writes (Dw, which equals the number of memory writes), D1 cache write misses (D1mw), and LL cache data write misses (DLmw).`

Comment: I am not seeing many missed reads here. That one line... you are bound to get a missed cache after so many times round the loop (near the end looks convincing to me). The number of misses compared to the number of reads doesn seem so bad (125000/8million+?) did I read that correctly?

Comment: @Galik While it doesn't seem bad, it's not 0, so it's not good enough ;)

Comment: @Galik Total COUNT is one million, I'm looping 125000 times (one million/8), so each iteration I'm getting one cache miss...Isn't that bad? Maybe I'm missing something and this is actually a good result.

Comment: Out of interest did you try incrementing the loop by just `1` and letting the optimizer do its own loop unrolling to see how that performs? (with -O3 also)?

Comment: @Galik With -O3 I get following result
`2,000,000    0    0 1,000,000 125,001 125,001         0    0    0          counter += v[i];` So one million iterations, 125k cache misses.

Answer (score 4):

It's important to first check the generated assembly code because that's what cachegrind is going to simulate. The loop that you are interested in gets compiled into the following code:

```
.L28:
addsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rax]
add rax, 64
addsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rax-56]
addsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rax-48]
addsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rax-40]
addsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rax-32]
addsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rax-24]
addsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rax-16]
addsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rax-8]
cmp rdx, rax
jne .L28
```

There are 8 read accesses per iteration and each is 8-byte in size. In C++, it's guaranteed that each element is 8-byte aligned, but up to two cache lines could be accessed per iteration depending on the address of the array of the `v` vector. cachegrind uses dynamic binary instrumentation to obtain the address of each memory access and apply its cache hierarchy model to determine whether an access is a hit or miss at each level in the hierarchy (it supports only L1 and LLC though). In this particular instance, it happens that a new cache line is accessed at `counter += v[i+6];`. Then, the next 7 accesses would be to the same 64-byte cache line. The source code line at which a new cache line is accessed doesn't impact the total number of misses reported by cachegrind. It will just tell you that a different source code line incurs that many misses.

Note that cachegrind simulates a very simplified cache hierarchy based on the machine it's running on. In this case, it is AMD 2400G, which has a 64-byte line size at all cache levels. In addition, the size of the L3 is 4MB. But since the total array size is 8MB, then the following loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<COUNT;i++) {
    v.push_back(i);
}
```

will leave only the second half of the array in the LLC. Now in the very first iteration of the second loop in which `counter` is calculated, the first line accessed will not be in the L1 or LLC. This explains the 1 in `D1mr` and `DLmr` columns. Then at `counter += v[i+6];`, another line is accessed, which is also a miss in both levels of the cache. However, in this case, the next 7 accesses will all be hits. At this point, only the access from `counter += v[i+6];` will miss and there are 125,000 such accesses (1 million / 8).

Note that cachegrind is just a simulator and what actually happens on a real processor can be and most probably is very different. For example, on my Haswell processor, by using `perf`, the total number of L1D misses from all of the code (both loops) is only 65,796. So cachegrind may either significantly overestimate or underestimate the miss and hit counts.

Comment: Yes, you have right. When I use reverse iterator: `for(auto it = v.rbegin(); it != v.rend(); ++it) { counter += *it; }`, the cachegrind reports only half total misses. I also tried `perf stat -e L1-dcache-load-misses ./a.out`, and it oscillates around ~105,000 on my computer (for both loops). Does that mean that AMD has worse prefetcher than Intel? I also didn't know that cachegrind is only simulator...

Comment: @AndrejKesely It not only depends on the hardware cache prefetchers, but also on cache replacement policies and physical addresses of the locations accessed (cachegrind only uses virtual addresses). If I disable prefetchers on Haswell, I get 191,997 L1D misses for the whole program (compared to 65,796 when prefetchers are enabled).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that this happens because vector buffer is not aligned on cache line boundary. That is sudden jump in cache misses marks a point when we proceed to a next line. So I suggest to check `v.data()` value.

Comment: Besides writing a custom allocator, is there any way the OP could get a vector with the right alignment?

Comment: @NathanOliver I think OP could just allocate an array of bytes and select an aligned starting position. Or just select an aligned starting position in vector of double.

Comment: Isn't aligning the vector to a cache line boundary just going to make the position where the cache misses move to a different place? Aren't you still going to get a cache miss just as regularly as you iterate through memory?

Comment: @Galik Yes, now I tried to allocate the vector with `double* v = (double *)aligned_alloc(64, COUNT * 8);` instead of `std::vector`, and the cache miss is on line `counter += v[i+0];`. I thought that CPU prefetcher will fetch data as they go.

Comment: @Galik Yes, but this misalignment explains why cache misses happen in the middle of the loop.

Comment: @VTT So can the loop be written without getting the cache-misses on every iteration? Or I'm without luck and all depends on CPU?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Since your data is too large to fit into the cache it obviously needs to be fetched from RAM at some point. I think the only way to help this is to manually write some prefetch assembly, using [`_mm_prefetch` intrinsic](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=fetch&expand=4363,4380,4360) for example.

Answer (score 1):

In my vision this looks absolutely okay if we forget about first 1M push-backs (8Mb... well maybe you do not have enough room in L2 for that). So if we will assume that our data is not in any level of cache then every time you read 8 doubles you have to ask RAM for next L1 line. So overall your stats looks fine. you are invoking QWORD reads 1M times and generate 125k requests to RAM due to simplet sequential access pattern.