# PostgreSQL poor cache performance or cache-misses

Tags: postgresql, performance, caching

PostgreSQLv14 source code compiled on  GCCv12 with --enable-debug.
And Benchmark environment used as  HammerDBv4.1 to test OLTP(TPC-C) on PostgreSQL
Here to the goal to identity cache misses(L1, L2 and L3 caches)annotate PostgreSQL source code or Methods() on running PostgreSQL bin's

Tired following commands:

1. valgrind --tool=cachegrind ./bin/tclsh8.6 ./hammerdbcli auto test_32vu.tcl (not shown PostgreSQL Methods() or calls)
2. valgrind --tool=cachegrind --trace-children=yes ./usr/local/postgresqlv14/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/postgres/data

example(excepted:[Cachegrind: Why so many cache misses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53231681/cachegrind-why-so-many-cache-misses))

But the above command not help out.And also tired with other tools like perf.
Perf also not helped on it :
https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2014/03/10/determining-whether-an-application-has-poor-cache-performance-2#amd_

Please let me know the right way to check annotate source code of cache misses in PostgreSQL by using Valgrind or other tools like perf.

Comment: What does 'not help out' mean?  What happened?  What did you expect to happen?  Do you have any experience in doing this with simpler programs than a full RDBMS?

Comment: with simpler program exercise got cache misses (Ref link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53231681/cachegrind-why-so-many-cache-misses) but in postgresql not able get cache misses with annotate c++/c code lines as shown in exercise